# Magento\Mtf\TestCase\Scenario Location file?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, unit-tests

I was installing some module and found that there are some test class that extend `Scenario` :

```
<?php
namespace Aheadworks\SocialLogin\Test\TestCase;

use Magento\Mtf\TestCase\Scenario;

/**
 * Preconditions:
 * 1. @TODO
 *
 * Steps:
 * 1. Set login block settings
 * 2. Flush cache
 * 3. Go to customer login page
 * 4. Click login via %provider%
 * 5. Submit credentials
 * 6. Go to customer account Social Accounts tab
 * 7. Assert linked account
 *
 * @group @TODO
 */
class CustomerSocialLoginTest extends Scenario
{
    /**
     * Run scenario
     */
    public function test()
    {
        $this->executeScenario();
    }
}
```

But the problem here is the `Scenario` class is not found anywhere, This troubles me when trying to run the unit test.

Do I need to install some other module or other extension in compose.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching I found that there is some additional steps in order to run the *Mtf* or `Magento Testing Framwork`.

You can find it more about how to install and run this test here :

```
cd <magento2_root_dir>/dev/tests/functional/
composer install
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_installation.html

Comment: After installation of mtf, you can find the file  Scenario.php in the folder mtf-master\Mtf\TestCase
Reference: [link] https://github.com/magento/mtf/tree/master